# Rails devise error "NoMethodError ... merge"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, rubygems

I was trying to make a User model with devise (so far in my application I have not had a problem with making Models or adding attributes). I run

```
rails g devise user
```

Which creates this:

```
  invoke  active_record
  create    db/migrate/20140930235224_devise_create_users.rb
  create    app/models/user.rb
  invoke    test_unit
  create      test/models/user_test.rb
  create      test/fixtures/users.yml
  insert    app/models/user.rb
  route  devise_for :users
```

Then I try to run

```
rake db:migrate
```

Which gives me the following

```
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `merge!' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper::Scope:0x9fc73a4>
/home/user/Desktop/MyApp/config/routes.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/user/Desktop/MyApp/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user/Desktop/MyApp/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

What could be the problem?

Line 2 for routes is:

```
devise_for :users
```

And line 5 for environment is:

```
Rails.application.initialize!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this may be a problem with Devise and the latest version of Rails. Have a look at these issues on Devise Github:

- [Issue 3158](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/3158)
- [Issue 3206](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/3206)
- [Issue 3151](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/3151)

This [blog post](http://alexp.github.io/2014/09/02/fixing-devise-after-rails-4-2-0-beta1-upgrade.html) explains that there is a branch with the fix, however, if you are going to be using this in production you should probably wait until Devise merge the fix into master.

Comment: Thanks, for the meanwhile should I just switch my gem list from this:
gem 'devise', '~> 3.3.0'
to this:
gem 'devise', '~> 3.3.0', :git => 'https://github.com/plataformatec/devise.git', :branch => 'lm-rails-4-2'

Comment: Yes, give that a try and it should fix the problem. Remember to swap it back before you go live.

Comment: Those issues are now closed and the most recent version of devise no longer has this problem.

Answer (score 22):

Check what devise version you have installed by running:

```
bundle show devise
```

With the latest version of Rails 4.2.0, devise will need to be upgraded to 3.4.0 or higher. To do so, specify in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'devise', '~> 3.4.0'
```

Then run:

```
bundle update devise
```

Comment: Thank you! My devise was out of date, before they'd merged this fix.

Answer (score 1):

Updating the version of devise from 3.3.0 to 3.4.0 in my Gemfile and running bundle update devise worked like magic for me. Im running rails 4.2.0.